# My Form Validation is not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am doing the email field validation. For this I have written a html code like this:

```
<form action="#">
           <span class="email-field" id="email-field">
             <input type="text" name="email-id" onFocus="if(this.value=='Your email ID'){this.value=''}" onBlur="if(this.value==''){this.value='Your email ID'}" id="email-id" />
             <input type="text" name="email-id" onFocus="if(this.value=='Please enter email ID'){this.value=''}" onBlur="if(this.value==''){this.value='Please enter email ID'}" id="error-email-id" class="hide"/>
           </span>
           <input type="submit" id="submit-button" class="subscribe-button" value="">

</form>
```

The Jquery I  have writte is for this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var filter = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.-])+@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
  URL = 'http://localhost:8000/'


  $("#submit-button").click(function() {
   email = $("#email-id").val()

 if($.trim($("#email-id").val()) === 'Your email ID' || !(filter.test($("#email").val())) ) {
  $('#error-email-id').fadeIn('slow').removeClass("hide");
  $('#email-id').fadeOut('normal').addClass("hide");
  $('#email-field').addClass("error-highlight");
  return false;
 }
 else {

  $.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: URL + "validate/" ,
  data: {"email-id": email},
  success: function(data) {
  },
  dataType: "json",
  });
  $('#form').fadeOut('normal').addClass("hide");
  $('#notification').fadeIn('slow').removeClass("show")
  return false;
 }


  });
```

The scnario is like this:-
1. First time I enter the `email` and if it `correct` , it makes a `successful call` to that `url`.
2. If I enter the wr`ong email` or if `validation fails` it gives me the appropriate class that is the text input field of id `'error-email-id'`. But When I click `submit button` No `JS call` happen. That is It doesn't call Any `Jquery` So no `URL`. It remains a `static` one.
Thanks in Advance !!!

Comment: u might want to check the formatting of the code,there seems to be couple of brace brackets missing

Answer (score 0):

By using `return false;` you prevent the form from being submitted in the normal way. You need to manually submit the form if validation succeeded (assuming that you add the ID `regForm` to the `form` element):

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: URL + "validate/" ,
  data: {"email-id": email},
  success: function(data) {
    $('#regForm').submit();
  },    // ...
```

You probably want to check the server's response `data` (from the *server-side* part of form validation) within the success function before you submit the form.